# Sections in table cells?

Tags: tables, sections-paragraphs

I'm working on a tool to export wiki content to LaTeX. In some cases the wiki syntax used generates sections inside table cells.

In HTML this translates to the following for example:

```
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <div>
               <h1>Extend your wiki</h1>
               <p>...</p>
            </div>
         </td>
         <td>
            <div>
               <h1>Create your application</span></h1>
               <p>...</p>
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I couldn't find anything about sections in table cells when googling and my conclusion so far is that it's not possible in LaTeX.

Could someone confirm this?

I'd need to find how I can transform this kind of structure in LaTeX. I guess the only solution that comes to mind would be to generate text in the same style as sections but without them being sections. They won't appear in TOC not be referenceable as sections but I don't see any other choice (unless it's possible in LaTeX ofc).

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A real section in a table cell is not possible. But how do you convert your documents?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\section{}` or similar commands inside `l`,`r` and `c` columns but inside of a `\parbox` (that is the same that use a `p` column):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{*{3}{p{2cm}c}}
    \section{11} bla bla bla ... & 12 & 13 & 14\\
    21 & 22 & \section*{23}  & 24\\
    31 & 32 & 33 & \parbox{2cm}{\section{34}}\\
    41 & 42 & 43 & 44\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```